# better way to write this list[2] as it throws exception

Tags: c#, .net

```
 viewModel.IsMember= Name.ToLower()
     .Equals(_sessionModel.Groups[2].MemberGroup, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Groups can contain only 3 and the Member group is in the 3rd item which is why I mentioned 2 as index. It works fine but when I write unit test without 0 and 1 items, it throw exception

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

Comment: So what does the `MemberGroup` property do for the non member-group groups (0 and 1)?

Comment: @itsme86: THank you for your concerns, well good question, group 1 and 2 dont have that property :(

Comment: But it worked properly when I ran code but only unit test fails (Could be because, in unit test I directly have only group 3 and not group 1 and 2 while in code my data contained group1,2,3 :)

Comment: What should the code do if there is no 3rd item in the list?  You need to understand that first, and then handle the case

Comment: I think you need to learn the basics of arrays, indexes and c# in general. It's not possible for groups 0 and 1 to "not have" that property since the array is of a specific type that declares that property, maybe you meant that the value would be empty instead?. The exception may be or may not be related to items 0 and 1 being missing depending on what `Groups` is. You need to post a [mcve] and explain what you want to do

Comment: Which testing environment are you using?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Agree, but I dont want to as my mindset is BA mindset while no job I get as BA so being a developer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `LastOrDefault()`

```
_sessionModel.Groups.LastOrDefault().MemberGroup
```

Comment: Based on the question and subsequent comments, this is incorrect,  If there is no 3rd item, the `MemberGroup` will not be present,

Comment: Thank you :) I am trying your code now :) Get back to you in a minute

Comment: This code is sort of working but throwing exception elsewhere.

Comment: This has actually worked in all scenarios, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what type contains `MemberGroup`, but let's say it's any type that derives from `IFoo`. So you need whatever item in the `Group` collection that has a `MemberGroup` property, meaning you need whatever item is castable to a `IFoo`. Thus you can use:

```
viewModel.IsMember = Name.ToLower()
    .Equals
    (
        _sessionModel.Groups.OfType<IFoo>().Single().MemberGroup, 
        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase
    );
```

If you're not sure if the `Groups` collection will contain an `IFoo`, you can use this code instead:

```
viewModel.IsMember = Name.ToLower()
    .Equals
    (
        _sessionModel.Groups.OfType<IFoo>().SingleOrDefault()?.MemberGroup ?? null, 
        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase
    );
```

This version will try to find an `IFoo`, but if it can't find any it'll behave as if `MemberGroup` was null, meaning that the comparison will probably return false. It might be clearer to write it like this:

```
bool IsMatch(sessionModel, name)
{
    var groupToMatch = _sessionModel.Groups.OfType<IFoo>().SingleOrDefault();
    if (groupToMatch != null) 
    {
        if (Name.Equals(groupToMatch.MemberGroup, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

viewModel.IsMember = IsMatch(_sessionModel, Name);
```

Comment: Sorry its too complex to understand, I am afraid to try, honestly I don't understand a single line, I am afraid. Thank you so much for your help, I am newbie